# How to add Format config file to VSCode workspace using Ionide

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, code-formatting, ionide

I want to add specific workspace setting for Formatting for F#

I see that [Ionide for VSCode](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp) uses [FsAutoComplete](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete) which in turns uses [Fantomas](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete) as the Formatter and that Fantomas has [config file](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas/issues/354) support (not documented), but I tried to add `.fantomas-config` and `fantomas-config.json` in the root of my project and the config file was ignored.

Ultimately what I want to achieve is:

1. [preserve new lines](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas/blob/master/docs/Documentation.md#--keepnewlineafter) made by me.
2. [set the "word wrap" column length](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas/blob/master/docs/Documentation.md#--pagewidth-number)
3. Other common formatting options like indentation etc.

Comment: Seems like adding `fantomas-config.json` in the root, should be working.